# Peltier generators series vs parallel

Tags: parallel, peltier

If you are using peltiers as generators do you get double the voltage if you connect two in series, and double the ampage if you connect two in parallel?

Answer (score 4):

The O.P. has got correct ideas.

"Peltier as a generator" is sometimes called *thermopile*.  I use this term, because it's shorter.

In **series**, the voltages will add up.

In **parallel**, the currents will add up.  But, a typical load sharing problem can occur.  You might need load sharing resistors.  The two thermopiles wouldn't be dead-on identical.  They would have slightly different impurities, and they will see slightly different temperature gradients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have now also come across the name TEG as a term, short for thermo electric generator. Thanks again

Comment: +1. Yet another name: [Seebeck effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_effect) generator.